# No IndexWriters activated - check your configuration

Tags: solr, nutch, hadoop2

Where did i mistaken  ? Iam Using hadoop 2.7.2, Solr 5.4.1 and nutch 1.12 version
Could any one help me out of this Query.

http.agent.name
 crawl

plugin.includes
protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|index-(basic|more)|query-(basic|site|url|lang)|indexer-solr|nutch-extensionpoints|protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(text|html|msexcel|msword|mspowerpoint|pdf)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika|metatags)|index-(basic|anchor|more|metadata)

fetcher.server.delay
  0.5

http.timeout
  10000

http.content.limit
  131027

**Running cmd** : bin/nutch index -Dsolr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collections crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/20160604193022

Indexer: starting at 2016-06-05 20:57:34
Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
Indexer: URL filtering: false
Indexer: URL normalizing: false
**No IndexWriters activated - check your configuration**

Indexer: number of documents indexed, deleted, or skipped:
Indexer: finished at 2016-06-05 20:57:38, elapsed: 00:00:04

Thanks

Narendra k

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to make sure that the plugin indexer-solr is included. Go to the file: conf/nutch-site.xml and in the property plugin.includes add the plugin, for instance:

> protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)

I hope it helps.